# Sync Google Calendar with work Outlook/Exchange without details

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, google-calendar

I'm using the free Google Calendar Sync to import my work calendar from Outlook into my 'life' calendar at Google Calendar. I would like to do a 2 way sync, but without my 'life' calendar events' details being imported into my 'work' Outlook calendar (i.e. Show colleagues that can see my work calendar I'll be unavailable at 15:00, but without the details).

I was unable to achieve this using various schemes, namely using the free Google tool to sync 2 way to a 2nd Google Calendar account to which I shared my 1st calendar without details (I guess it doesn't work since it does not sync non-primary calendars).

I'm sure this is a common problem for the working person.... any ideas?

p.s. I'm using Outlook 2007 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have tried this already and it might not work... but try it!

```
Click on settings in the top-right corner of Google Calendar.

Click on the name of your Personal Calendar

Click on *Share this Calendar*

Click *Make this Calendar Public*

Click *Share only my free/busy information (Hide details)*
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but I would like to refrain from giving this (admittedly sanitized) information to all of the outside world