# Merging google calendar and outlook calendar (or copy all events from one to the other)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, google-calendar

## `I have,`

***- my outlook calendar that all the people in the company can see request meetings.***

***- my google calendar that other google users can see and request meetings. Also many apps can directly write meetings to my google calendar.***

I imported the google calendar into outlook so now I have both my calendars under "My Calendars" in outlook. But both are different calendars.

## `I need,`

***a way for the people at work to see the blocks of the other calendar as well. Ideally they should appear as private, but I don't care if not.***

So, I need either, to import the google calendar not as a separate calendar but inside my outlook calendar, or find a that all the events added to the google calendar are automatically copied to the outlook one.

Is this possible in some way?

I saw some semi-related questions,
[link1](https://superuser.com/questions/402310/how-do-i-migrate-calendar-events-from-one-outlook-calendar-to-another-while-pre)
[link2](https://superuser.com/questions/198967/sync-google-calendar-with-work-outlook-exchange-without-details)
[link3](https://superuser.com/questions/732998/how-can-i-make-my-other-calendars-visible-from-my-outlook-calendar)
[link4](https://superuser.com/questions/1430153/sync-outlook-calendar-used-at-work-and-google-calendar-used-for-my-family-wi)
[link5](https://superuser.com/questions/111095/sync-google-calendar-with-outlook-2007-calendar)
None seems to have an answer. But in my case, I do not want to be able to change anything on the google calendar from outlook, I only want the events to be visible for others when they set to see my calendar.

Version: I'm using Office 365 ProPlus 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, with options in Outlook alone, we could only add google calendar as a separate calendar and could not automatically add its items to your Outlook calendars. To achieve effects like that, you might need Add-ins or VBA scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Third party tool http://phw198.github.io/OutlookGoogleCalendarSync, which is free and open source, should be able to do what you describe. Sync from Google to Outlook  and select the "merge" option along with setting all synced items in the target calendar to private.